# tabhost image as back ground or icon in tab host full height

Tags: android, tabs

[image: tab]

this is the tab in my mobile app im wondering how to maximize the height of the image icon in the tab. is it possible to maximize that image or im doing it wrong im also open to make the image as back ground i tried making it but unfortunately for me the image stretch and it looks bad. tried a couple of tutorials like [this](http://andmob.wikidot.com/faq-tabsize) it says i should put `tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));` but it didnt change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
..........................
```